# How to use cAdvisor data to calculate network bandwidth usage (per month) in grafana?

Tags: docker, prometheus, grafana, promql, cadvisor

I’m using Prometheus (incl. cAdvisor) and Grafana to monitor my server, on which docker containers are running. cAdvisor gives me the data for my docker containers.

I’m trying to monitor the `network bandwidth usage` for the selected time (on the top right corner of grafana). It should output a value like `15 GB` (for the selected month) or `500 MB` (for the selected day).

---

**My approach so far**:

In Grafana I am using the `Stat` UI with `Value options > Calculation` of `Total`, while using the following query:

```
sum(rate(container_network_receive_bytes_total{instance=~"$host",name=~"$container",name=~".+"}[1m]))
```

*(FYI: I have a `container variable` to filter the values for the selected container. This is why you can find the part `,name=~"$container"` in the query above.)*

---

The problem with the approach above is, that the outputted values do not seem to be right, because if I change the time range to a smaller one, I will get a bigger value. For instance, if I select `Last 2 days` the output is `1.19 MB`, while selecting `Last 24 hours` gives me `2.38 MB`. Of course, this does not make sense, because `yesterday + today` can’t be smaller than just `today`.

What do I oversee? How can I achieve it to output correct values?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you could have overlooked, but I did have success in setting up a total RAM usage stat panel, as well as an average RAM usage (per container) stat panel using the code below:

Total RAM usage:

```
sum(container_memory_usage_bytes{image!=""})/1024/1024
```

Average RAM usage:

```
sum(container_memory_usage_bytes{image!=""})/1024/1024 / count(container_last_seen{image!=""})
```

My `Value` option for `Calculation` is `Last*` on both of those.

Did you ever get your intended total bandwidth usage stats to work?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following query:

```
sum(increase(container_network_receive_bytes_total{instance=~"$host",name=~"$container",name=~".+"}[$__range]))
```

Comparing to the original query, it substitutes [rate](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/metricsql/#rate) with [increase](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/metricsql/#increase) for calculating the increase for the `container_network_receive_bytes_total` [counter](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyconcepts/#counter) over the selected time range in Grafana. It also substitutes `1m` in square brackets with [`$__range`](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/template-variables/#use-interval-and-range-variables) in order to properly take into account all the [raw samples](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyconcepts/#raw-samples) on the selected time range.